# font styling in a JavaScript drop down list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down list that when a visitor clicks on an item it automatically takes them to a URL with variables for that item.

Everything works great but I want the Variable "show_name" to be bold and the variable "start_date" to be normal weight.

I have tried the "strong" tag and the "div" tag and nothing seems to work.

```
<cfoutput>
         <select name="lps_surf1" class="style7"  onChange="MM_jumpMenu('self',this,0)">
          <cfloop query="gtshws2">
              <option value="sel_itms.cfm?show_name=#show_name#" target="_self">
              <div style="opt">#show_name#</div>-#DateFormat(start_date, "MMM. DD, YYYY")#
              </option>
          </cfloop>
        </select>
</cfoutput>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about  <div style="opt"><b>#show_name#</b>-#DateFormat(start_date, "MMM. DD, YYYY")#</div>

Comment: Hi Roberto. Didn't work. Also i thought the <b> tag had faded away.

Comment: What is the style for your class opt?

Comment: Try <div style="opt"><span class="boldclass">#show_name#</span>-#DateFormat(start_date, "MMM. DD, YYYY")#</div> and add css for this class

Answer (score 0):

Nope. `<option>`is styled by the platform they are on and attempting to style just one part of them won't work as the html is stripped away.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I did try just about everything including voodoo. As Rosanna Rosadanna use to say "IT'S ALWAYS SOMETHING"!